# Inequality for $u \in L^r(\Omega)$: $\int_{\Omega} (a_1+a_2|u|^{r/s})^s dx \leq a_3 \int_{\Omega} (1+|u|^r)dx$

Tags: analysis, lp-spaces

This question is from one of the steps of the Proof of Proposition B.1 in Appendix B of P. H. Rabinowitz's "Minimax Methods in Critical Point Theory with Applications to Differential Equations."

Let $u \in L^r(\Omega), r,s \ge 1,$ and $a_1,a_2 \ge 0$. How do you prove the following inequality? (We can choose $a_3$ to be an arbitrary constant.)
$\int_{\Omega} (a_1+a_2|u|^{r/s})^s dx \leq a_3 \int_{\Omega} (1+|u|^r)dx$.

Comment: Is $\Omega$ bounded?

Comment: Yes. $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded domain. (Sorry I left this out!)

Comment: You can write $f=a_1,\ g=a_2|u|^{r/s}$ and then apply the triangle inequality for the $L^s(\Omega)$ norm.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I still don't quite see how this works. The triangle inequality says that 
$\left( \int_{\Omega} (a_1+a_2|u|^{r/s})^s dx \right)^{1/s} \leq \left( \int_{\Omega} a_1^s \right)^{1/s} + \left( \int_{\Omega} a_2^s |u|^r \right)^{1/s}$. 
Raising both sides to the $s$, we have 
$\int_{\Omega} (a_1+a_2|u|^{r/s})^s dx \leq  \left( \left( \int_{\Omega} a_1^s \right)^{1/s} + \left( \int_{\Omega} a_2^s |u|^r \right)^{1/s} \right)^s$. What can we now do the right hand side?

Comment: The rhs is equal to $(a_1\mu(\Omega)+a_2\|u\|_{L^r(\Omega)}^{r/s})^s\leq 2^s (\max\{a_1^s\mu(\Omega)^s,a_2^s\|u\|_{L^r(\Omega)}^{r}\})\leq 2^s\max\{C_1,C_2\|u\|^r_{L^r(\Omega)}\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will use the following inequality: 
$$\forall a,b\ge 0, s\ge 1: \, (a+b)^s\leq 2^{s-1}(a^s+b^s)$$
This is easily proved by noting that the function $f(t)=t^s$ is convex for $t\ge 0$ and therefore you have $$f(\frac{1}{2}a+\frac{1}{2}b)\leq \frac{1}{2}f(a)+\frac{1}{2}f(b)\Leftrightarrow \big(\frac{a+b}{2}\big)^s\leq \frac{1}{2}a^s+\frac{1}{2}b^s$$
$$\Leftrightarrow (a+b)^s\leq 2^{s-1}(a^s+b^s)$$
Now you apply this inequality for $1$ and $|u(x)|^{r/s}$ pointwise for every point $x$ in $\Omega$ and use the monotonicity of the integral.
$$\int\limits_{\Omega}{(a_1+a_2|u|^{r/s})^sdx}\leq \int\limits_{\Omega}{\max{\{a_1,a_2\}^s(1+|u|^{r/s})^s}dx}\leq \max{\{a_1,a_2\}}^s\int\limits_{\Omega}{2^{s-1}(1+|u|^r)dx}=a_3\int\limits_{\Omega}{(1+|u|^r)dx}$$
where $a_3:=\max{\{a_1,a_2\}}^s2^{s-1}$